# C Segmentation fault using Argv[]

Tags: c, cs50

I am new to C programming and I am getting a Segmentation Fault when passing a single character and trying to vailidate if it is a digit.

Here is a sample:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (isdigit(argv[argc-1]))
    {
        printf("Use only one Argument%i\n", argc);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you running this program?

Comment: `argv[argc-1]` is of type `char*`, while `isdigit` is taking `int` in the range of `unsigned char` or `EOF`. Shouldn't segfault though. But who knows, UB is UB.

Comment: ah oops I didn't even think of the type error, I'm used to my compiler catching that kind of thing for me

Comment: `argv[argc-1]` should be `argv[argc-1][0]` to check the first character of the argument.

Comment: The message you're printing doesn't make sense for the `if` test. It has nothing to do with the number of arguments.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Of course it should generate a segment fault (in the sense that is entirely reasonable). The `<ctype.h>` functions are typically implemented as a lookup table. when the `char *` argument to `isdigit` is converted to `int`, it most often results in a large `int` value, and then the table lookup goes far out of bounds.

Comment: always check arguments, `if (--argc) { ... }` to avoid disasters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eugene said, `argv[argc-1]` is of type `char*` as it was meant to hold a string.
The segmentation fault is probably a result of lookup.

Assuming you would like to test the first character of the last argument, this should be written like this:

```
if (isdigit(argv[argc-1][0]))
{
    printf("Use only one Argument%i\n", argc);
    return 1;
}
```

You can also use the '*' notation to defer to the first char, but I believe `[0]` will be slightly more readable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I am also posting an answer that checks if all the inputs are digits. So it does not just look at the first input from the command line. This way you can put any amount of digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        //need to figure out how many "words" user wrote
        for(int i = 1; i<= argc-1; i++) {
                int stringLength = strlen(argv [i]);
                for( int j =0; j < stringLength; j++) {
                        if (!isdigit(argv[i][j]) ){
                                printf("Use only digits\n");
                                return 1;
                        }
                }

        }
        return 0;

}
```

```
Example one : 

./stackQuestion 1
```

```
Example two: 

./stackQuestion 1o1
Use only digits
```

```
Example three:

./stackQuestion 1 1 101
```

Comment: this way you can put any amount of digits.

Comment: You should edit your answer instead of commenting on it

Comment: Sorry about that  I did edit it, thanks for the advice.